# How to route load from one server machine to another on falure?

Tags: networking

I have two HP Proliant servers.  Both have same configuration and same data (Replicated). Currently all production load is on Server A, while Server B is idle. Now I want to configure my network such a way that if Server A is in any error state (hang/restart/down) all load will be redirected to Server B. How can I acheive this?

Comment: For starters, CPU != server.

Comment: I have edited your question to make it more clear that you are talking about 2 servers, not 1 server with 2 CPUs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want a load balancer.  This is a hardware or software device that routes traffic to a group of servers, and monitors them to make sure it doesnt route traffic to ones that are offline or not responding.

Most can do active/standby routing or active/active to share the workload between the servers.

Some loadbalancers can also work as a pair with their own failover, so the load balancer itself doesnt become a single point of failure.